# PLSQL Select first value if exists, otherwise select another value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table like this

```
ID NTYPE
1 0
2 0
3 1
4 2
```

I need a select to get all IDs according of a list of NTYPE (1 to N), but if any of the NTYPE list does not exist then get where NTYPE = 0..

For example:

- If NTYPE list = 1 then The IDs must be 3
- If NTYPE list = 1,2 then The IDs must be 3,4
- If NTYPE list = 2,3 then The IDs must be 1,2,4... 1 and 2 because there is not records where ntype = 3 then get where NTYPE = 0...

I can make a procedure that can do this but I would like do it in a select

Is it possible? Any Idea?

Comment: Hello, What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

You want to construct a derived table with the ntypes you are looking for.  Then you can use this with the logic that you want.  Here is one version:

```
with n as (
      select 1 as ntype from dual union all
      select 2 as ntype from dual
     )
select t.*
from t
where t.ntype in (select ntype from n)
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.ntype = 0 and
      exists (select 1
              from n
              where not exists (select 1 from t where t.ntype = n.ntype)
             );
```